# R function to list labels of columns of .sav-Dataset

Tags: r, label, gles

I want to be able to read trough the variable/columns to choose useful variables for my analyis. Therefore i want to have the labels as well, since the variable names are not human-readable.

I downloaded the GLES-Dataset ZA7729 as .sav-file from https://gles.eu/bundestagswahl-2021/ and imported it into R-Studio via "import from Stata".
Then i'm able to see the variables/columns with labels,
[my loaded data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmDau.png)
but there are so many variables, that i want a more readable format, like having a list of them printed. I got close to what i wanted by using
`str(ZA7729_v1_0_0)`
[str(ZA7729_v1_0_0)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHCDT.png)
but it prints a lot of additional information that i don't need and make it hard to read. I only want the line with @label or -attr( ,"label") for each variable/column
I tried iterating over str(ZA7729_v1_0_0) but then i found out that it only prints and does not return anything, so that's not an option. I pretty much want colnames(ZA7729_v1_0_0) but with the human readable labels instead of just the variable name.

Comment: The fact that the dataset came from Stata seems irrelevant to your question, so I removed that tag.

Comment: We could help more if you would make your problem reproducible. In this particular case, you could include the 1st row of your dataframe by pasting the results of `dput(ZA7729_v1_0_0)` in a code chunk. In general, good advice about how to make reproducible examples for questions can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Yeah you wouldn't want that...its several thousand lines and just breaks of because of the length, as far as i can see. But there isn't really a problem, it's just that i'm looking for a feature. I want a human-readable list of the variables (of which there are many) with their label, like for the first row, the variable "study" i want to get the label "Studiennummer" and so on

Answer (score 1):

I think the `names` function will do what you want. For example,

```r
df <- data.frame(a = rnorm(5),
                 b = rnorm(5),
                 c = rnorm(5))
names(df)             
#> [1] "a" "b" "c"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Unfortunately no,  this outputs the same as colnames(), i.e. the incomprehensible variable names, not the labels. The output would be
> names(ZA7727_v1_0_0)       
  "study"                    "version"                  "doi"                     
   "field_start"              "field_end"                "sample"                  
   "lfdn"                     "kp21_010"                 "kp21_011a"               
  "kp21_011b"                "kp21_011c"                "kp21_180" 
...